# Moving household goods to Brazil on tourist visa

Tags: regulations, brazil

I'm relocating from Canada to Brazil to be with my common-law partner, who is Brazilian and is currently there. I would like to take some of our household goods, books and mementos with me when I fly as extra luggage, because it is cheaper than shipping it. 
I would like to know if I can bring in household goods on a travel visa, as I will be applying for permanent resident status once in Brazil. 
I have called and emailed the Brazilian Consulate here and have not heard back. 
Does anyone have experience moving to Brazil under similar circumstances?
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your visa type say "no permanent" it's how you will be handled by customs, they cannot be sure you will stay here for long or not. I'm don't sure about it but since you don't bring jewellery or (too many) Iphones I guess you are ok. Tourists with family/friends here brings all sort of mementos. If you partner if here tell him to call Receita Federal to ask about customs and Polícia Federal to ask about visa